# Is there any way to display a toggle button in asp.net MVC using CheckBoxFor and Bootstrap

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

Is there any way to have a toggle button in asp.net MVC instead of CheckboxFor?

I am using twitter bootstrap but I can't find any classes which has that effect.

Any help would be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try: https://bttstrp.github.io/bootstrap-switch/

```
<input type="checkbox" name="my-checkbox" checked><input type="checkbox" name="my-checkbox" checked>

$("[name='my-checkbox']").bootstrapSwitch();
```

Comment: Thanks For your reply. I did what you suggested and toggle buttons are working. but if I use mvc html helper like @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.DoDetection), the toggle button are appearing twice. Did you ever encountered this problem?

Comment: ok, got it working with a slight change: $(document).ready(function () {
        var checkBox = $("[name='DoReplayDetection']").not('[type="hidden"]');
        checkBox.bootstrapSwitch('onColor', 'danger');
    });

Comment: above given link is broken

Answer (score 1):

Is the Single Toggle button not right for you?
http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#buttons